# Facebook - How to Add Description to Like

Tags: facebook

I cannot find any documentation regarding how to add the description to the Facebook Like button (highlighted in red in the image). Any guidance?

[image: Facebook Description]

Comment: Could you show some code, it will be easier for everyone to say what is missing. Thanks.

Comment: I think I've found what I was looking for which was `og:description`. I am testing to make sure that is correct. http://www.joshspeters.com/how-to-optimize-the-ogdescription-tag-for-search-and-social

Comment: You are right `og:description` is the thing you need.

Comment: @YervandKhalapyan Can you post your response as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to Add `og:description` Open Graph Meta tag. For checking if everything is done right (facebook scraper can see everything correctly) You can use Facebook [Debug tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)

Comment: Do you know if there a list of all the meta tags Open Graph looks for or uses?

Comment: You can find the whole documentation here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-objects/#creating

Comment: Where do you use the like plugin? You'd better also go through this link:https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/maximizing-distribution-media-content/